# Distinguishing parent model's children with Django inheritance

Tags: python, django

Basically I have a Base class called "Program". I then have more specific program model types that use Program as a base class. For 99% of my needs, I don't care whether or not a Program is one of the specific child types. Of course there's that 1% of the time that I do want to know if it's one of the children.

The problem is that if I have let's say, a SwimProgram model and a CampProgram model using Program as their base, that it's problematic to find out what they are without a bunch of try/except blocks. What I want is something like the following:

```
program = models.Program.objects.get(id=15)
if program.swimprogram:
    ## do stuff
elif program.campprogram:
    ## do stuff
else:
    ## do other stuff
```

Of course this throws DoesNotExist exceptions. I could either use try/excepts which are uglier, or I could have Program have a 'type' field that the children set on save. Both are doable, but I'm curious if anyone has any better methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried hasattr()?  Something like this:

```
if hasattr(program, 'swimprogram'):
    # ...
elif hasattr(program, 'campprogram'):
    # ...
```

If you are unsure about this approach, try it out in a simple test app first.  Here are two simple models that should show if it will work for you and the version of django that you are using (tested in django-1.1.1).

```
class Archive(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Archive: %s" % self.pub_date

class ArchiveB(Archive):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "ArchiveB: %s" % self.pub_date
```

And then giving it a spin in the shell:

```
> a_id = Archive.objects.create(pub_date="2010-10-10").id
> b_id = ArchiveB.objects.create(pub_date="2011-11-11").id
> a = Archive.objects.get(id=a_id)
> b = Archive.objects.get(id=b_id)
> (a, b) # they both look like archive objects
(<Archive: Archive: 2010-10-10>, <Archive: Archive: 2011-11-11>)
> hasattr(a, 'archiveb')
False
> hasattr(b, 'archiveb') # but only one has access to an ArchiveB
True
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? I'm pretty sure that `program` has both attributes. The DoesNotExist exception only occurs when trying to access them (since inheritance is modeled with a OneToOne relationship)

Comment: yw f4nt.  I did pretty much the same thing when i figured it out for myself.  @piquadrat, I added an little example to show how it can work.  Thanks for the nudge to add the example.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of weeks ago, someone on the django-developers mailing list introduced a very interesting extension to Django's ORM that makes QuerySets return subclassed objects instead of objects of the parent class. You can read all about it here:

http://bserve.webhop.org/wiki/django_polymorphic

I haven't tried it myself yet (but certainly will), but it seems to fit your use case.

Comment: The link is dead, I think the corresponding project is https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic but it looks like it never moved since its initial commit...

Answer (score 0):

**// Update**

As pointed out in the comments to this post I got the question wrong. The answer below will not solve the problem.

---

Hi f4nt,

the easiest way I can think of right now would be the following:

```
program = models.Program.objects.get(id=15)

if program.__class__.__name__ == 'ModelA':
  # to something

if program.__class__.__name__ == 'ModelB':
  # to something
```

To make this a bit better you could write a method in the base model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

  def instanceOfModel(self, model_name):
    return self.__class__.__name__ == model_name
```

That way the code from above would look like this:

```
program = models.Program.objects.get(id=15)

if program.instanceOfModel('ModelA'):
  # to something

if program.instanceOfModel('ModelB'):
  # to something
```

But as you can imagine this is ugly. You could look into the [content type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#ref-contrib-contenttypes) framework which might help you to do the same except more elegent.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't hink this will work. Django docu clearly says: *QUERYSETS STILL RETURN THE MODEL THAT WAS REQUESTED* . So if you request Program objects then `program.__class__.__name__` will be `Program`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Felix. But I tried it in the django shell and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, just did a quick test, and it will return "Program".

Comment: I think I got want you want to say. You are only fetching the Program objects (not SwimProgram etc.) and now want to know what it really is. Sorry.

Comment: No worries :) I'm just going to have the children set a Type field on save instead. I don't necessarily like it, but it'll work until I think of something better. Try/Except would work if I didn't plan on subclassing Program a few more times, just afraid the code'll become a rat nest with try/except.