# How can I know that an instance of a model was created by an instance of a child model?

Tags: django, inheritance

I've got a model Child inheriting from a (non abstract) model Parent.
For a given instance parent of Parent, how can I know if it's a Child?

If it is,

```
parent.child
```

returns the child, but otherwise it returns a DoesNotExist exception.

Is a try/except the only way to check that?

Thanks

jul

# EDIT

I've just find the same question here: 
[Distinguishing parent model's children with Django inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202232/distinguishing-parent-models-children-with-django-inheritance).

And the answer is....

```
hasattr(parent, 'child')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just find the same question here: 
[Distinguishing parent model's children with Django inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202232/distinguishing-parent-models-children-with-django-inheritance).

And the answer is....

```
hasattr(parent, 'child')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is a try/except the only way to check that?

More or less.

If you only want an existence check, you can avoid the exception by saying `Child.objects.filter(parent=parent).exists()`, but if you want to do something with the child if it exists, it's better to just access it directly and handle the `DoesNotExist`.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `instanceof(parent, Child)`.  It will return True for Child instances, False for Parent instances.

Comment: (This won't work: the poster's question is about Django model inheritance, not Python inheritance.)

Comment: I guess this wasn't asked for. If `child` is an instance of `Child`, then it is also stored in the `Parent` table, so the question is (if i got it right), how to determine if an object retrieved from the `Parent` table is a child...