# get all the parents class from inner Meta in django?

Tags: django, inheritance, meta

I wonder if it's possible to get all the parents classes from the inner Meta class.

```
class Abc(A,B,C):
   class Meta:
     # I wanna know A,B,C without explicitly listing them again. 
     # something like self.parents()
```

**Edit** : The actual problem..

[Tastypie accessing fields from inherited models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753113/tastypie-accessing-fields-from-inherited-models/20771396#20771396)

I needed to list parents classes in meta.

```
class Abc(A,B,C):

   class Meta:
       list_of_fields_of_parents = A.fields + B.fields + C.fields
```

Comment: What do you need them for? Especially inside the Meta class? What is the * actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Abc.__bases__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__). For example:

```
class Meta:
    list_of_fields_of_parents = [b.fields for b in Abc.__bases__]
```

Because this doesn't work for the `Meta` *inside* the `Abc` class, you can store your base classes in a list to keep things DRY:

```
abc_bases = [A, B, C]

class Abc(*bases):
    class Meta:
        list_of_fields_of_parents = [b.fields for b in abc_bases]
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. It's kind of a chicken/egg problem, because the `Abc` class is not completely constructed at that point. I'll edit my answer with another possibility...